# WSO2 Governance Registry - How to install the WSO2 Registry on WebLogic

Tags: registry, weblogic, wso2

I have a requirement to install WSO2 Governance Registry on WebLogic application server.
However, the documentation links [here](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/Governance411/Governance+Registry+Samples#) are disabled. Any idea how I can generate war files from Governance Registry in order to deploy them in WebLogic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using G-Reg 4.1.1,
Go to the bin directory and run the following ant command.

**ant createWAR**

ajithn@ajithn:~/wso2/products/wso2greg-4.1.1/bin$ ant createWAR

Buildfile: /home/ajithn/wso2/products/wso2greg-4.1.1/bin/build.xml

createWAR:
     [copy] Copying 12 files to /home/ajithn/wso2/products/wso2greg-4.1.1/tmp/wso2
     [copy] Copied 8 empty directories to 2 empty directories under /home/ajithn/wso2/products/wso2greg-4.1.1/tmp/wso2
     [copy] Copying 23 files to /home/ajithn/wso2/products/wso2greg-4.1.1/tmp/wso2/WEB-INF/lib
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/ajithn/wso2/products/wso2greg-4.1.1/tmp/wso2/WEB-INF/lib
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /home/ajithn/wso2/products/wso2greg-4.1.1/tmp/wso2/WEB-INF/classes
     [echo]
     [echo] **WSO2 Carbon webapp successfully created in /home/ajithn/wso2/products/wso2greg-4.1.1/tmp/wso2**
     [echo]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL